# Do not understand google call for analytics (one line is wrong)

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'am just playing for learning reasons with some google code.
All world is using the following google-code for analytics.
If i look at this line:

```
 i[r]=i[r]||function(){  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)  }
```

it must be wrong for me.

i[r] is representing i['ga']

If I do not give the argument 'ga' to the call I will get an error in the next line. That's means to me that the ||function(..    will never be called.

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){  // r is the 'ga' argument
      i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;
      i[r]=i[r]||function(){  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)  },  //for what is this line?
      i[r].l=1*new Date();
      a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
      a.async=1;
      a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
```

I can't believe that this is an issue by google. Is there something i do not know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, it helps to "unminify" things a little, so if you substitute the parameters values in, this

```
i[r]=i[r] || function(){
   (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)
},
```

becomes this

```
window.ga = window.ga || function(){
   (window.ga.q = window.ga.q || []).push(arguments)
},
```

And if you replace all the minification tricks, you get this:

```
// check whether the Analytics object is defined
if (!('ga' in window)){
   // Analytics object not defined, so define it
   window.ga = function(){
   // Add tasks to the queue
   window.ga.q.push(arguments);
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: OK thanks. One more question:
If there is no ga for what reason I push(arguments). 
Or: What is this for window.ga.q.push(arguments)?

Comment: If the real ga ever arrives, it will pick things up from this queue, and executes them. If there's no ga planned at all, why are we discussing this code in the first place?